# CSV Validation In magento 2

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport

I am working on **Magento 2.2.5**, need to validate **CSV** file for import.

1. How to skip row? like I don't want to save any data of row 2, then
   how to skip that row.
2. I am using only one attribute set, so I don't want to fill that in **CSV**, so how will i make it default from program. Please any one help me.

Comment: Have you got solution or any query?

Comment: no, not yet , still finding the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it will help you.

In your controller file that `$postUrl` points to:

```
protected $csv;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv
)
{
     $this->csv = $csv;
}

//The function name should match your controller path
public function import($file)
{
     if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) 
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));

     $csvData = $this->csv->getData($file['tmp_name']);

     foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
         if ($row > 0){
             //Start your work
         }
     }
     die();
}
```

Note:

1. The `$data` is an array object already. It will look like `array(
   0 => 'UPS',
   1 => 'One Night Service'
   ......
   )`
2. I added `if ($row > 0)` to skip first row as it's the attribute row only.
3. You must `die()` the execution after your job done.
   I assume your controller is custom made. If you want to override the core controller.

For more reference [Click here](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-readwrite-csv-file-from-magento/)

Comment: this is the way only i created my controller, but row is not yet skipped. still magento read 2nd line.

Comment: This is a demo code example you have to use function to skip `array value` like using `array_slice` `array_pop` etc.

Comment: check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php